# error: expected color reference but got (raw string) res/launch_background

Tags: flutter, android-styles

tried building flutter apk for my app but encountered these 2 errors
[terminal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i684m.png)
[terminal picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csVVo.png)

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}

}

allprojects {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}


this is android build gradle



def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the             local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}`

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

[values-night(styles.xml)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8gVI.png)
[values(styles.xml)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neIKa.png)

tried everything possible but still cannot get this error rectified, since I'm a very beginner at flutter and dart a detailed solution is expected and will be really grateful for that.

Comment: You need to provide a color value instead of the broken reference in styles and values.xml or make a proper resource reference. Currently your `item` is just a string in both those files.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.